# Why am I getting Error Code: -122 SQL State: 42803?

Tags: db2, odbc

Using ODBC connection to a DB2 instance with the select statement below it returns the following error:

> Error Code: -122 SQL State: 42803

Can someone help me identify which part of the code below is raising the error

```
SELECT
  SAB089.ZCREPRE0.CREPREDOS as ContractCode, 
  SAB089.ZCLIENA0.CLIENACLI as ConsentCode,
  SAB089.ZCREPRE0.CREPREAGE as Branch,
 (case
when SAB089.ZCREPRE0.CREPRECTA='7' then 'Open'
when SAB089.ZCREPRE0.CREPRECTA='8' then 'Closed'
end) as PhaseOfContract,
  (case
when SAB089.ZCREPRE0.CREPRECTA='6' then 'GrantedButNotActivated'
when SAB089.ZCREPRE0.CREPRECTA='7' then 'GrantedAndActivated'
when SAB089.ZCREPRE0.CREPRECTA='8' then 'SettledOnTime'
end) as ContractStatus,
  'Installment' as TypeOfContract, 
  (case
when SAB089.ZCREPRE0.CREPRENAT = '757' then 'Vehicule'
                        when SAB089.ZCREPRE0.CREPRENAT = '756' then 'Equipement'
                        when SAB089.ZCREPRE0.CREPRENAT = '758' then 'Immobilier'
                        end)  as PurposeOfFinancing, 
  SAB089.ZCREDOS0.CREDOSDEV as CurrencyOfContract, 
  Cast(SAB089.ZCREDOS0.CREDOSMNT as DECIMAL(19,2)) as TotalAmount, 
  SAB089.ZCREAVI0.CREAVIMON as InstallmentAmount, 
  SAB089.ZCREPLA0.CREPLANPC as NumberOfInstallments, 
  Cast(SAB089.ZCREPRE0.CREPRECAP as DECIMAL(19,2)) as OutstandingAmount, 
  Cast(SAB089.ZIMPECH0.IMPECHMON as DECIMAL(19,2)) as PastDueAmount, 
  SAB089.ZIMPECH0.IMPECHDTI as PastDueDays, 
  SAB089.ZIMPDOS0.IMPDOSECH as NumberOfDueInstallments, 
  Cast(SUM(SAB089.ZCREAVI0.CREAVIMON + SAB089.ZCREAVI0.CREAVIMIN + SAB089.ZCREAVI0.CREAVITVA + SAB089.ZCREAVI0.CREAVIAM1)as DECIMAL(19,2)) as TotalMonthlyPayment, 
  (case
when SAB089.ZCREPLA0.CREPLAPCA = 'U' then 'FinalDay'
                        when SAB089.ZCREPLA0.CREPLAPCA = 'M' then 'Days30'
                        when SAB089.ZCREPLA0.CREPLAPCA = 'T' then 'Days90'
                        when SAB089.ZCREPLA0.CREPLAPCA = 'S' then 'Days120'
                        when SAB089.ZCREPLA0.CREPLAPCA = 'A' then 'Days360'
                        end)
                        as PaymentPeriodicity, 
  {fn substring(SAB089.ZCREMAD0.CREMADDMD,5,2)} || '-' || {fn substring(SAB089.ZCREMAD0.CREMADDMD,3,2)} || '-' || {fn substring(SAB089.ZCREMAD0.CREMADDMD,1,2)} as StartDate,
  {fn substring(SAB089.ZCREAVI0.CREAVIECH,5,2)} || '-' || {fn substring(SAB089.ZCREAVI0.CREAVIECH,3,2)} || '-' || {fn substring(SAB089.ZCREAVI0.CREAVIECH,1,2)} as RealEndDate
FROM
 SAB089.ZCREAVI0, SAB089.ZIMPDOS0, SAB089.ZIMPECH0, SAB089.ZCREMAD0
  INNER JOIN SAB089.ZCREPRE0 ON (SAB089.ZCREPRE0.CREPREETA=SAB089.ZCREMAD0.CREMADETA and SAB089.ZCREPRE0.CREPREAGE=SAB089.ZCREMAD0.CREMADAGE and SAB089.ZCREPRE0.CREPRESCE=SAB089.ZCREMAD0.CREMADSER and SAB089.ZCREPRE0.CREPRESSE=SAB089.ZCREMAD0.CREMADSSE and SAB089.ZCREPRE0.CREPREDOS=SAB089.ZCREMAD0.CREMADDOS and SAB089.ZCREPRE0.CREPREPRE=SAB089.ZCREMAD0.CREMADPRE)
   INNER JOIN SAB089.ZCREPLA0 ON (SAB089.ZCREPLA0.CREPLAETA=SAB089.ZCREPRE0.CREPREETA and SAB089.ZCREPLA0.CREPLAAGE=SAB089.ZCREPRE0.CREPREAGE and SAB089.ZCREPLA0.CREPLASER=SAB089.ZCREPRE0.CREPRESCE and SAB089.ZCREPLA0.CREPLASSE=SAB089.ZCREPRE0.CREPRESSE and SAB089.ZCREPLA0.CREPLADOS=SAB089.ZCREPRE0.CREPREDOS and SAB089.ZCREPLA0.CREPLAPRE=SAB089.ZCREPRE0.CREPREPRE)
   INNER JOIN SAB089.ZCREDOS0 ON (SAB089.ZCREDOS0.CREDOSETA=SAB089.ZCREPRE0.CREPREETA and SAB089.ZCREDOS0.CREDOSAGE=SAB089.ZCREPRE0.CREPREAGE and SAB089.ZCREDOS0.CREDOSSER=SAB089.ZCREPRE0.CREPRESCE and SAB089.ZCREDOS0.CREDOSSSE=SAB089.ZCREPRE0.CREPRESSE and SAB089.ZCREDOS0.CREDOSDOS=SAB089.ZCREPRE0.CREPREDOS)
   INNER JOIN SAB089.ZCREEMP0 ON (SAB089.ZCREDOS0.CREDOSETA=SAB089.ZCREEMP0.CREEMPETA and SAB089.ZCREDOS0.CREDOSAGE=SAB089.ZCREEMP0.CREEMPAGE and SAB089.ZCREDOS0.CREDOSSER=SAB089.ZCREEMP0.CREEMPSER and SAB089.ZCREDOS0.CREDOSSSE=SAB089.ZCREEMP0.CREEMPSSE and SAB089.ZCREDOS0.CREDOSDOS=SAB089.ZCREEMP0.CREEMPDOS)
   INNER JOIN SAB089.ZCLIENA0 ON (SAB089.ZCLIENA0.CLIENACLI=SAB089.ZCREEMP0.CREEMPNCL)
   LEFT OUTER JOIN SAB089.X89ADRESSE ON (SAB089.X89ADRESSE.ADRESCLI=SAB089.ZCLIENA0.CLIENACLI)
   INNER JOIN SAB089.ZCLIENB0 ON (SAB089.ZCLIENA0.CLIENAETB=SAB089.ZCLIENB0.CLIENBETB and SAB089.ZCLIENA0.CLIENACLI=SAB089.ZCLIENB0.CLIENBCLI)
   INNER JOIN SAB089.ZCLIENC0 ON (SAB089.ZCLIENA0.CLIENAETB=SAB089.ZCLIENC0.CLIENCETB and SAB089.ZCLIENA0.CLIENACLI=SAB089.ZCLIENC0.CLIENCCLI)
   LEFT OUTER JOIN SAB089.ZCLILIB0 ON (SAB089.ZCLILIB0.CLILIBCLI=SAB089.ZCLIENA0.CLIENACLI)

WHERE
  ( 
  {fn substring(SAB089.ZCLILIB0.CLILIBVAL,13,1)}  =  'O'
  AND  SAB089.ZCREMAD0.CREMADDMD  >= '1120101'
  AND  SAB089.ZCREPRE0.CREPRECTA  IN  (6, 7, 8)
  AND  SAB089.ZCLIENA0.CLIENADOU  =  'N'
  )
```

Comment: Remove columns from the `SELECT` list one by one until you no longer see the error.

Comment: This is the problem   Cast(SUM(SAB089.ZCREAVI0.CREAVIMON + SAB089.ZCREAVI0.CREAVIMIN + SAB089.ZCREAVI0.CREAVITVA + SAB089.ZCREAVI0.CREAVIAM1)as DECIMAL(19,2)) as TotalMonthlyPayment,

its forcing me to use a group by function

Comment: Because `SUM()` is an aggregate function, which requires grouping. Do you simply want to add the four column values in a row, may be?